# How to insert null value to Sqlite with SQLiteStatement

Tags: android, android-sqlite, sql-insert

I try to save to Sqlite `Event`

```
public class EventDao{

    private SQLiteStatement insertStatement;
    private SQLiteDatabase db;

    private static final String INSERT =
            "insert into " + EventsTable.TABLE_NAME + "(" + EventsColumns.WHO + ", "
                                                          + EventsColumns.WHAT
                                                          + ") values (?, ?)";

    public EventDao(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        this.db = db;
        Log.w(TAG, EventDao.INSERT);
        insertStatement = db.compileStatement(EventDao.INSERT);
    }

    public long save(Event type) {
        insertStatement.clearBindings();
        insertStatement.bindString(1, type.getmWho());
        insertStatement.bindString(2, type.getmWhat());

        return insertStatement.executeInsert();
    }
//...
}
```

Everything works OK when both `getmWho()` and `getmWhat()` return non-`null` values. But when I try to save Event which has `Who` field empty (and thus `getmWho()` returns `null`) I'm getting error

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: the bind value at index 1 is null
```

How to fix this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `bindNull()` instead of `bindString()` to bind values that are null.

Or, since you're clearing all bindings before binding new values, just don't bind any null strings. When you don't bind any value to a position, the default value of null is assumed.

Comment: Maybe I'm a nitpicker but bindNull() binds null and not a "value" that is null. You can't use insertStatement.bindNull(1, type.getmWho()).

Answer (score 0):

Simply ask `if(value != null)` before binding a value which could be null.

I never understood why people often `bindNull()` if there wasn't bound any value before. Seems pointless. Especially if you use `clearBindings()`.

[API reference for clearBindings:](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteProgram.html#clearBindings())
Clears all existing bindings. Unset bindings are treated as NULL.